# AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'model_selection'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

when I want to use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` to split train set and test set,it raises error  this like:

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'model_selection'
```

My code is as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
data = pd.read_csv('SpeedVideoDataforModeling.csv',header=0,)
data_x = data.iloc[:,1:4]
data_y = data.iloc[:,4:]
x_train , x_test, y_train, y_test = 
sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(data_x,data_y,test_size = 0.2)
```

In Pycharm,the scikit-learn package version is 0.19.1.

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 16):

You need

```
import sklearn.model_selection
```

before calling your function

Comment: This worked for me. In addition to importing sklearn,  I added this 'import sklearn.model_selection"  too.

Comment: unless you are using many functions/classes of `model_selection`, then don't do this because you wont know where it comes from

Comment: yeah but why, add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can import like `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`. An example from the official docs :)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
>>> X
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> list(y)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
...
>>> X_train
array([[4, 5],
       [0, 1],
       [6, 7]])
>>> y_train
[2, 0, 3]
>>> X_test
array([[2, 3],
       [8, 9]])
>>> y_test
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Pycharm you have to reload the Python Console for sklearn to show all its components. If you do not all you see is sklearn.base and a few other general things. I just recreated this myself and found this answer.